# Configuring 2 different domain on 2 different ports using nginx opening same website on both domain instead of their respective content

Tags: node.js, angular, linux, nginx

```js
server {
listen 80;
server_name www.domain1.com;

    root path_to_1st_website;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;

}
server {
listen 80;
server_name www.domain2.com domain2.com;

    root path_to_2nd_website;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3004;
}
```

I am using the above configuration for my nginx server. But in domain1.com and domain2.com both are showing the content of the second config i.e. domain2.

I want domain1 should show data from the 1st website and domain2 should show the data from the 2nd website.

Comment: Are you certain that the content of "root path_to_1st_website;" is actually the content of "root path_to_1st_website;"? Also, have you tried to seperate the configuration files ? i.e /etc/nginx/conf.d/foo.conf and /etc/nginx/conf.d/bar.conf ?

Comment: yes I tried separating the configuration in different files. Also the root path for both the configuration is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain1.com domain1.com;

    root path_to_1st_website;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;

}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain2.com domain2.com;

    root path_to_2nd_website;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3004;
}
```

I resolved the issue by using `server_name` with both `www` and `non www`.